# Is there any reason to provide COM servers to wrap atomic types and to trivial interfaces

Tags: com

I just started playing with COM. Like my fellow C/C++ programmers I found COM ugly for many practical reasons, until the moment I've read [this](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2004/06/repeat-after-me-com-is-just-an-interface-layer.html) and [this](http://www.moserware.com/2008/01/finally-understanding-com-after.html). If COM is all about interoperability, it makes sense that COM should remain at the border-edge of any implementation. I think this would be a good practice.

However, I discussed with a the guy how  implemented a piece of code I'm working on (to investigate a heap corruption issue). And he didn't seem to approve the concept of putting COM on the edge. He still enumerates the benefits of providing COM interfaces for all and any. So,

**Is it really a bad design to put COM everywhere in an implementation?**

PS: In the implementation I'm working on, every thing is COM server. There are: `ComNode`, `ComProperty`, `ComString`, and even `ComReal` and `ComInteger`.

Comment: Add some samples of the idl to make your question more clear.

Comment: There's such thing as Automation-compatible types. If all your types are Automation-compatible interop and marshalling often get much easier. Integers and BSTRs are Automation-compatible.

Comment: @xMRi Sorry if my question isn't clear. Actually there is no pertinent code related to my question. I just wished to know whether COM programming is what i understood. I do not get the reason to provide a COM server to interface integers.

Comment: As long as those integers are long or short (C++) I also see no reason the define a ComInteger class. Also this would make it nearly impossible to use such a com interface in the normal meanings inside a VB-Script if you cant to multiply two integers.  And I see currently no reason the hide the int value inside a class, as long as it is not a class with a special meaning and behaviour.